# What is the result of $\sum\limits_{0}^{n}\binom{n+r}{r}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinations, binomial-theorem

What would be a combinatorial approach to find out $\sum\limits_{r=0}^{n}\binom{n+r}{r}$?

Comment: It seems likely you intended the index of summation to be $r$, ranging from $0$ to $n$.  If you like someone can make this edit for you.

Comment: What have you tired so far?

Comment: Considering the ${n+r}\choose{r}$ as elements of the pascal triangle is quite useful.

Answer (score 2):

We have $\sum\limits_{r=0}^n\binom{n+r}{r}=\sum\limits_{r=0}^n\binom{n+r}{n}$.  The second sum is equal to  $\binom{2n+1}{n+1}$ by the more general hockey stick identity.

Comment: there are various combinatorial proofs for the hockey stick identity.